# With HTML5 Application Cache, how to cache only resources (e.g- css and js files), not the main documents (e.g- index.php)?

Tags: local-storage, html5-appcache

I am using **HTML5 Application Cache** in my dynamic application to cache the js and css files only. But if I reload the php file couple of times the php document gets cached as well and no dynamic contents are shown.

A spanshot from network panel is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8wQ8.png)

Here is the cache manifest-

```
CACHE MANIFEST
css/bootstrap.min.css
css/main.css

NETWORK:
*

FALLBACK:
/ /offline.html
```

**Is there any way, I can restrict the PHP documents to be cached?**

Answer (score 0):

i just found the solution, after long hours.

If you don't want to cache your specific page, don't include the manifest attribute on this specific page on the html tag, and this page will always go on the fallback page if you are offline.